# problem with an javascript inputs in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, integer, console.log

I have a exercise where i need to take two inputs and check if they both equal to one.

If yes console.log positive else console.log false

I tried something like this:

```js
function isPositive(firstNum, secondNum) {
  if (firstNum !== 1) {
    console.log('no positive')
  } else if (secondNum === 1) {
    console.log('positive')
  }
}

isPositive(5, 7)
isPositive(5, 10)
isPositive(5, 6)
isPositive(5, 1)
isPositive(1, 1)
```

and then when i run it in chrome console this

```
isPositive(5, 7)
not positive
undefined

isPositive(5, 10) 
not positive
undefined

isPositive(5, 6) 
not positive
undefined

isPositive(5, 1) 
not positive
undefined

isPositive(1, 1)
 yes positive
undefined
```

Comment: Your code seems to work

Comment: your code is working properly! The `undefined` pops up by the browser itself!
try to write `var i = 1;` in the console and you will see `undefined` too ;)

Comment: aw cool thank you guys :)

Comment: Yes that's why!
Anyway your code won't work in this case: isPositive(1, 2);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`undefined` is return because you do not explicitly return something on that function. If we would do some refactoring, you will see, that it is works as suppossed.

```js
function isPositive(a, b) {
  return (a === 1) && (b === 1) ? 'positive' : false
}

console.log(isPositive(5, 7))
// => false
console.log(isPositive(5, 10))
// => false
console.log(isPositive(5, 6))
// => false
console.log(isPositive(5, 1))
// => false
console.log(isPositive(1, 1))
// => 'positive'
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is working properly except for the case:

```
firstNum = 1
secondNum > 1
```

because won't enter in the first if and nither in the else.
By the way you can use the && operator to say if first is true AND second is true then...

```
function isPositive(firstNum, secondNum){
   if (firstNum === 1 && secondNum === 1) {
        console.log('positive')
   } else {
        console.log('no positive')
   }
}
```